# How to fit text inside nodes at bottom in pack layout in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I created d3 pack layout.Text is added in nodes. Requirement is text should be fit in circular nodes in such way that Text should be at bottom, proportional to node size and should be fit inside node.but text is either overlapping or hides behind another node or not proportional to nodes as in JSFiddle examples
http://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/11/,

http://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/12/,

http://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/13/
.So how to resolve all issue with one code?

```
            function treeLayout(nodes){                 
                var node = diagramLayout.selectAll(".node");
                node = node.data(nodes.descendants(), function(d) {
                            return d.uid; 
                            });     
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("height", nodeHeight)
                .attr("width", nodeWidth)                   
                nodeEnter.append("circle")
                        .attr("id", function(d) { return "node-" + d.data.name; })
                        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
                        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.depth); });
                nodeEnter.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });                
                var nodeText = nodeEnter.append("text")
                      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
                      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.data.name + ")"; })
                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .style("stroke", "#000")
                        .style("stroke-width", "0.1px")
                        .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return d.r-(d.r/d.data.name.length); 
                        })
                        .style("font-family", "sans-serif") 
                      .style("font-size", function(d) { 

                      return d.r/(d.data.name.length)+ "px";                          
                })  
            }       
            }
```

Comment: Any solution to this issue?